# In UWP: Contact.Phones property does not return IList<ContactPhone> as stated in the docs

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In a UWP App, I am picking a contact using

`var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();`

Then I am serializing the returned contact object using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) as the following:

`string c = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);`

But the problem is that the properties in the contact object that are (should be) of type `IList` such as Phones, Emails, Addresses ... etc are not serialized correctly. They are empty JSON arrays.

Upon checking, I figured out that the problem is that these properties are not returning objects of classes implementing the interface `IList` as supposed! Instead, they return objects of type `System._ComObject`.
So when calling `contact.Phones.GetType().FullName`, I get: `System._ComObject`.

And the same also with `contact.Emails`, `contact.Addresses` ... etc.

Any help to get the properties correctly and consequently serialize the contact object correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most UWP types are actually COM objects under the hood. There's some magic to make them appear and act as the C# projections they claim to be, but if you try to do things with Reflection (as JSON.NET does), reality rears its ugly head.

Some quick testing reveals two possible options:

1) Forcing the value returned from `contactPicker.PickContactsAsync()` into a real C# object can be accomplished by running it through a LINQ `.ToList()` (or `.ToArray()`, I imagine) call. You'd have to do this for each collection property on each `Contact` object, but at the end of it, you'd have a happily serializable C# object.

2) Write your own JSON.NET serializer for the `Contact` object that understands how to access and serialize each property individually. If you do something like `var singleContact = await contactPicker.pickContactAsync()`, you can still do `singleContact.Addresses[0]` or other such list-like things the way you'd expect to in C# code, meaning that writing such a serializer would be very possible.